# Rows returned outside WHERE IN condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query like:

```
select gift.id as giftId, gift.title, count(vouchercode.id) as stock 
from gift 
inner join vouchertemplate 
left join vouchercode 
on gift.voucherTemplate = vouchertemplate.id 
and vouchertemplate.id = vouchercode.template 
and vouchercode.given = 0 
and gift.id in (5, 6, 7) 
group by gift.id
```

I expected all rows to have `gift.id` to be one of `5,6,7` but I get a row with `4` too. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You have left join. You need:

```
select gift.id as giftId, gift.title, count(vouchercode.id) as stock 
from gift 
inner join vouchertemplate 
left join vouchercode 
on gift.voucherTemplate = vouchertemplate.id 
and vouchertemplate.id = vouchercode.template 
and vouchercode.given = 0 
where gift.id in (5, 6, 7) 
group by gift.id
```

When you put that in `JOIN` condition - it is used only for the join. For this reason you get *4*. You have to put that in `WHERE` clause.

If this query not correspond to your business logic, please explain in details what kind of result do you need to redesign the query.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `join`s, you should put the conditions between each pair of tables in an `on` clause between each `join`, in one long `on` clause at the end.  In fact, most databases (and ANSI) require this syntax.

This doesn't actually fix your problem.  That is caused by the condition in the `on` clause rather than the `where` clause:

```
select g.id as giftId, g.title, count(vc.id) as stock 
from gift g inner join
     vouchertemplate vt
     on g.voucherTemplate = vt.id left join
     vouchercode vc
     on vt.id = vc.template and vc.given = 0 
where g.id in (5, 6, 7) 
group by g.id ;
```

A `left join` keeps all records in the first table *regardless of whether or not the `on` condition evaluations to true*.  So, filtering on the first table has no effect for a `left join`.  Similarly, filtering on the second table has no effect for a `right join`.

The solution is to put conditions on the first table in the `where` clause.

Also notice the use of table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.